# How to install auditd from source in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, auditd, source

I want to set up auditd to collect its logs from remote server.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS.

This feature [seems to be disabled](http://bl0gg.ruberg.no/2016/01/auditd-in-ubuntu-not-listening/) into Ubuntu auditd package.

So, I'm going to install it from source.

Where do I can download right auditd source code?
Are there any issues with installing auditd from source?

**Update:**
I tried to download audit_2.3.2.orig.tar.gz from [package page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/ru/trusty/admin/auditd) and from project page (on https://people.redhat.com/sgrubb/audit), but when I run `.configure` get an error

> Could not find libwrap headers

Answer (score 1):

In general: [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) contains a home page for each package.

That home page has a number of interesting sections, including in the right column a number of links, one of which is to the home page of the original open source project but you can also download both the original source and the modified Debian/Ubuntu sources that were used to build the original package.

[This answer](https://serverfault.com/a/415318/37681) has a nice description of how to modify an existing Debian/Ubuntu (source) package, which might be more maintainable than just downloading the source.

Comment: Thanks!

I tried to download audit_2.3.2.orig.tar.gz from [package page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/ru/trusty/admin/auditd) and from [project page](http://people.redhat.com/sgrubb/audit/), but when run .configure got an error 'Could not find libwrap headers'.  

How to use audit_2.3.2-2ubuntu1.dsc file?  

Now, reading and trying 'rebuilding package' manual.

Comment: You need set up a correct development environment, the topic of which is much more suitable for StackOverflow, with the development files/packages containing the headers (for all  dependancies) such as for instance `libwrap0-dev`

Comment: Thank you, @hbruijn! 'apt-get install libwrap0-dev libcap-ng-dev swig' solved installing problems. Also, I tried to rebuild package (with fixed 'debian/rules' file). It's not too complex as it seems. Now I have installed and working auditd.

Answer (score 1):

First

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get source apt-get source
sudo apt-get build-dep audit
cd audit-2.3.2
```

Then: fix 'debian/rules' file. You need to remove '–disable-listener' option.

Finally:

```
sudo dpkg-buildpackage -b
cd ../
sudo dpkg -i auditd_2.3.2-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

And if you need plugins:

```
sudo dpkg -i audispd-plugins_2.3.2-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to setup [audit subsystem](http://people.redhat.com/sgrubb/audit/) on Ubuntu 14.04 distribution, you just run the following command line:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install auditd
```